# Open PDF file with page number/index in UWP apps

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Is there any option to Open a PDF file that is available in local state folder (inside app installation directory) with the page number. There is one method ([launchFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchfileasync?view=winrt-19041)) to open such files but I don't find any option to pass page number/index to open specific page.

Thank you! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

UWP provides the [PdfDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.pdf.pdfdocument) class for parsing PDF files, and this class provides the `GetPage` method for obtaining the object of the corresponding page (`PdfPage`) through the index.

This is simple code:

```cs
PdfDocument pdfDocument;
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("xxx.pdf");

pdfDocument = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(file);
using (var firstPage = pdfDocument.GetPage(0))
{
    var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await firstPage.RenderToStreamAsync(stream);
    // do something...
}
```

Here is the complete code example:

- [PDF document sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PdfDocument)

Comment: Thank you so much. Gone through the samples and documentation. Few more confusions, it is like rendering PDF into image. Is it possible to render all the pages and go to the specific page, he should have the PDF viewing experience rather than just  displaying single image. Looking forward to hear!

Comment: Hello, you can get the total number of pages of the pdf file through `PdfDocument.PageCount`, and then you can create and get all the pages through a loop, and fill them in the Image. But this is not recommended (it consumes a lot of memory). You can try to load the content before and after the specified page first. For example, if you need to scroll to the fifth page at the beginning, then you can load the first five pages first, and then scroll Adjust the bar to the bottom (you can use `ScrollViewer.ChangeView` or `ListView.ScrollIntoView`), and then load subsequent pages